# Thymeleaf classappend for more than two alternatives

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a `badge` used inside the bootstrap card. There are 3 possible values for this badge. `FREE`, `BASE`, `PREMIUM`.
I want to use different colors for these 3 values.

Div class looks like this:

```
<div class="badge text-white position-absolute" th:text="${content.getCategory()}"></div>
```

How can I update my class on the fly to use `bg-dark` for `BASE`, `bg-primary` for `FREE`, and `bg-danger` for `PREMIUM`?

I tried to use [literal substitutions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) for `th:classappend` but I could not find a way to make it work with triple possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<div class="badge text-white position-absolute"
     th:with="category=${content.category.toString()}"
     th:classappend="|${category == 'BASE' ? 'bg-dark' : ''}${category == 'FREE' ? 'bg-primary' : ''}${category == 'PREMIUM' ? 'bg-danger' : ''}|"
     th:text="${category}"></div>
```

This also works by defining an inline map:

```
<div class="badge text-white position-absolute"
     th:with="categoryClass=${ {'BASE': 'bg-dark', 'FREE': 'bg-primary', 'PREMIUM': 'bg-danger'} }"
     th:classappend="${categoryClass.get(content.category.toString())}"
     th:text="${content.category}"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither one has worked. None of these options appends a class and the badge values are displayed without any style.

Comment: For the second option; If I do something like this:  `th:classappend="${categoryClass.get('BASE')}"` I get badges with black backgrounds. It works. But If I use `th:classappend="${categoryClass.get(content.category)}"` no style is applied. I guess I can't read the value from inline map.

Comment: Ok, it worked when I added `toString()` to the get method. Please update your answer with this small change and I will hapily accept your answer. :)

`th:classappend="${categoryClass.get(content.category.toString())}"`

Comment: So this was an ENUM? I can't really guess what you're doing in code if you don't provide the details :P.  I did add the toStrings though.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought all capital values would give a hint but I agree, I should've added that information. Anyway, thank you.